# Asignar botones a cada elemento de un array

Tags: javascript

tengo un array de series (total_series)y dentro un array de actores para cada serie que muestro en una lista en el html, no consigo crear un botón por cada actor para poder eliminarlo haciendo click...

```
 total_series[2] :

 let serieA = new SerieTV("Los Simpsons", "Entretenimiento", ["Homero","Lisa"]);
 let serieB = new SerieTV("Los Soprano", "Drama", ["Tony","Mario","Luigi"]);
 let serieC = new SerieTV("Friends","Comedia",["Rachel","Ross","Monica","Joey"]);
```

y la función que muestra el arreglo y crea los botones para cada actor:

```
function muestraSerie(){




var lista = document.getElementById("muestra_series");//referencia del document

total_series.forEach(function(element,index){   
            
     var item = document.createElement('li');   

        const boton2 = document.createElement("button");   //no puedo asignar este botón a cada actor
        boton2.type = 'button'; 
        boton2.innerText = 'Elimina actor';

        const boton = document.createElement("button");   //boton para eliminar serie
        boton.type = 'button'; 
        boton.innerText = 'Elimina serie';
          
    
        boton.onclick= function(){                
            
            total_series.splice(index,1);
            
            document.getElementById("muestra_series").innerHTML="Lista Actualizada";
            muestraSerie();                      //Actualizo lista
        }
    var contenido = document.createTextNode("POSICION = " +index +' '+"TITULO = " +element.titulo+' '+"TEMA = "+element.tema+' '+"ACTORES = "+element.actores+' '+ "ACTOR FAVORITO = "+element.actorFavorito +'  ');

           
    lista.appendChild(item);   
    item.appendChild(contenido);
    item.appendChild(boton);
});
```

}`

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea del código es que el elemento padre donde se encuentra el actor tenga un id que permita encontrarlo fácil con la función que se ejecuta al presionar el botón, puede variar dependiendo de la forma en la que se quieran mostrar los datos pero la idea se mantiene.

```js
let serieA = {
  nombre: "Los simpsons",
  categoria: "Entretenimiento",
  actores: ["Homero", "Lisa"],
};

let serieB = {
  nombre: "Los simpsons",
  categoria: "Entretenimiento",
  actores: ["Homero", "Lisa"],
};

let series = [serieA, serieB];

// esta es la función principal que recorre las series
// y crea los elementos principales
function pintarSeries() {
  // se limpia el contenedor cada vez que se pintan las series
  document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML = "";
  
  
  series.forEach((serie, index) => {
  
    let ulElement = document.createElement("ul");

    let liElement = document.createElement("li");
    liElement.innerText = serie.nombre;

    let botonEliminar = document.createElement("button");
    botonEliminar.onclick = () => {
      // al eliminar se remueve el elemento 
      // del arreglo de series en el indice actual
      series.splice(index, 1);
      // luego se remueve el elemento html
      ulElement.remove();
      // se vuelven a pintar las series
      pintarSeries();
    };

    botonEliminar.innerText = "eliminar";

    liElement.appendChild(botonEliminar);

    let ulInterno = document.createElement("ul");

    agregarActores(ulInterno, serie.actores);
    liElement.appendChild(ulInterno);

    ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
    
    
    // agregar al contenedor la lista de series
    document.getElementById("contenido").appendChild(ulElement);
  });
}

function agregarActores(ulElement, actores) {
  // iterar la lista de actores
  actores.forEach((actor, index) => {
    // crear un elemento de la lista li
    let liElement = document.createElement("li");
    
    // agregar un elemento de texto al li
    // que contiene el nombre del actor
    liElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(actor));

    // crear el botón que servirá para eliminar el actor
    let botonEliminar = document.createElement("button");
    // agregarle un texto al botón
    botonEliminar.appendChild(document.createTextNode("eliminar"));
    // agregar la función que se ejecutará cuando se presione
    // el botón
    botonEliminar.onclick = () => {
      // se remueve el elemento del arreglo de actores
      // se remueve el elemento html
      // y se pinta de nuevo la lista
      liElement.remove();
      actores.splice(index, 1);
      pintarSeries();
    };

    // agregar botón al li
    liElement.appendChild(botonEliminar);
    // agregar el li al ul
    ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
  });
}

pintarSeries();
```

```html
<div id="contenido">

 
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Lobos, agradezco tu aportación,  en este caso el elemento padre sería el objeto "Serie"?todas las series y sus actores[] están dentro de otro array(total_series), este array lo recorro con un total_series.forEach(function(serie,index){}  y lo muestro dentro de una lista <li> a cada serie le asigno un botón, lo que no puedo hacer es dar un botón a cada actor...

Comment: Antes de trabajar en otro ejemplo, una pregunta, al eliminar el actor con el botón, se debe eliminar de la lista? o solo eliminarlo visualmente?

Comment: se debería eliminar de la lista como sucede con la serie cuando la elimino, para lo cual he utilizado slice(), con tu ayuda ya logré insertar un botón por actor, accediendo al índice de actores con un iterador, ahora lo que necesitaría es asociar cada botón con un actor de manera que un botón borra un actor, se que no es nada eficiente mi planteo pero así es como lo necesito

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo completo.